# pull request has an Empty merge conflict

Tags: git, reactjs, merge, bitbucket

I've been trying to solve a merge conflict with my pull request, but I have no idea what the conflict actually is in this situation.  Here is my conflict down below.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TwitterLogin from 'react-twitter-auth';
import { CheckBox, Post, Button } from 'main-page';
+<<<<<<< destination:b1385546be420fe8cca8c365f0041782ed789aac
+=======
+
+>>>>>>> source:e12a01ed3b9fc04c9d669bf41a74b30a1f97ef96


 // main code down below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just looks like the `source` version has an extra space in there.  This can be a common thing, and to resolve this you can probably just delete the entire block from `<<<<<<<` to `>>>>>>>`.

Note that to avoid this in the future, you should always look at a side-by-side diff of each file you plan to commit against the version with which you started.  Then, such things as extra spaces would be visible, and you could remove them before committing.